# Obtain Cert issuer X500 Principal name with xmlsec

Tags: openssl, xml-signature, xmlsec

I am trying to port a Java code that made some time ago to iOS, i compiled xmlsec with openssl and no xslt support.

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

X509Certificate cert = ...
cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName();
cert.getSerialNumber();
```

edit: The code could be in xmlsec or openssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used xmlsec to generate the xmlsignature and had to parse that info out of it...